# Laravel 5.7 LeftJoin Delete Row From Both Tables

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have been looking around for ways to delete some rows from joined tables in Laravel 5.7. I have three tables(Inventories, Vehicles and Vimages) and I want to join them all together and delete the rows together. Does anyone know if this is possible?

The reason I am trying to do this is because the **Vehicles** and **Inventories** table have a one to one relationship, which only the Inventories table has an id which is used to sort the vehicles(**Dealer Id**). So I can select multiple vehicles from Inventories with the **dealer id** and delete them but I cannot do the same with the Vehicles table.

Thanks

My Join:

```
Inventory::leftJoin(
                'vehicles', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'inventories.vehicle_id'
            )->leftJoin(
                'vimages', 'vimages.inventory_id', '=', 'inventories.id'
            )->where(
                'inventories.dealer_id', '=', \Auth::user()->dealer_id
```

Comment: how is your database model? Is there a foreign key relationship between the vehicles and inventories table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a foreign key constraint with cascading deletes you can achieve this.  Eloquent supports this but you need to set this up in your migrations as follows.

```
$table->foreign('vehicle_id')->references('id')->on('vehicles')->onDelete('cascade');
```